# Eclipse complains about name clash when code is copied to another project

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I have this interface and its implementation. Eclipse (Indigo Build id: 20110615-0604, jdk1.6.0_29 on Windows 7 Starter) does not complain in one project, but once I copied them to another project, it complains about "Name clash: The method setChildren(List) of type Node has the same erasure as setChildren(List) of type NodeInterface but does not override it". 
The 2 projects are in the same workspace. I have tried reinstalling Eclipse with no avail. Is this an Eclipse issue or the code is fundamentally wrong ? How to remedy it ?

```
public interface NodeInterface {
    public List<? extends NodeInterface> getChildren();
    public void setChildren(List<? extends NodeInterface> children);
}

public class Node implements NodeInterface {

    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public List<? extends NodeInterface> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<? extends NodeInterface> children) {
        this.children = (List<Node>) children;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because in that project you are in a Java version < 1.5. Generics were added in Java 1.5. To remedy: `Right click on the project` > `Properties` > `Java Compiler` > `pick-up a version >= 1.5`

That's what's happening if you are i.e. in java 1.4:

[image]

and when you switch to say Java 1.5 everything looks good:

[image]